# Usage of mutexes in interporcess sync in c

Tags: c, windows, process, synchronization, mutex

I've been searching for a while and I've decided to ask as I'm unable to find a right answer.

Actually I've got two processes

Process 1:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// This process creates the mutex object.

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hMutex; 

    hMutex = CreateMutex( 
        NULL,                        // default security descriptor
        TRUE,                       // mutex owned
        TEXT("AnotherMutex"));  // object name

    if (hMutex == NULL) 
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError() ); 
    else 
        if ( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS ) 
            printf("CreateMutex opened an existing mutex\n"); 
        else printf("CreateMutex created a new mutex.\n");

    if(WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE) == WAIT_FAILED)
        printf("Error while waiting for the mutex.\n");
    else
        printf("Mutex openned by second process.\n");

    CloseHandle(hMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

Process 2:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// This process opens a handle to a mutex created by another process.

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hMutex; 

    hMutex = OpenMutex( 
        MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS,            // request full access
        FALSE,                       // handle not inheritable
        TEXT("AnotherMutex"));  // object name

    if (hMutex == NULL) 
        printf("OpenMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError() );
    else printf("OpenMutex successfully opened the mutex.\n");

    if(!ReleaseMutex(hMutex)){
        printf("Error while releasing the mutex.\n")
    }

    CloseHandle(hMutex);

    return 0;
}
```

So when I run the first process it just doesn't wait for the second process to release the mutex but; as the mutex is created owned, nonsignaled, it shouldn't wait till some process/thread releases it and then print the message?

Comment: In the first process you are waiting for a mutex you already own, so the wait will be satisfied immediately; in the second process you are releasing a mutex that you *don't* own, which is illegal.  I think Eugene has it right, you should be using an event instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have confused between two types of synchronization objects: `Mutexes` and `Events`.

`Mutexes` are generally used to protect access to shareable resource. At the entrance to the critical section the `WaitForSingleObject` on the `Mutex` should be called. If `Mutex` is not obtained by another execution unit (thread or process) this execution unit obtains it and continues running, otherwise it is locked until other process releases it. At the end of the critical section the `Mutex` should be released. See [Using Mutexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927(v=vs.85).aspx). That is why your process is not suspended.

`Events` on the other hand are used to synchronize execution units or to notify something. When one creates an event it specifies its signaled state. When `WaitForSingleObject` is called and the event is in the non-signaled state the execution unit will be suspended until something signals the event. See [Using Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915(v=vs.85).aspx)

Bottom line in your case you should use the `Event`